# How to align a button and a search bar beside each other

Tags: html, css

I am currently learning HTML and CSS. My problem is: I have a button and a search bar with the search bar currently below the button. I have tried different solutions but to no avail. What should I do so that the button and the search bar are beside each other
Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Dashboard</title>
<style type="text/css">

table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;

}

p.pos_right {
position: relative;
left: 20px;
}

img {
display: inline-block;
z-index:-1;
}

#mine{
display: inline;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align:center;">    
<p>Most Number of Referrals for the month of <img src="Red-Ribbon.jpg" alt="redribbon" width="200" height="200" style="vertical-align:top"> </p>
</div>

<div class = "mine" align ="center">
<button style="background-color:yellow" onclick="window.location.reload()"><b>UPDATE</b></button>
<table class = "one" style=border="1" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
<tr> 
<td style="border-style:solid none solid solid;border-color:#4B7B9F;border-width:1px;">
<input type="text" name="zoom_query" style="width:100px; border:0px solid; height:17px; padding:0px 3px; position:relative;"> 
</td>
<td style="border-style:solid;border-color:#4B7B9F;border-width:1px;"> 
<input type="submit" value="" style="border-style: none; background: url('searchbutton3.gif') no-repeat; width: 24px; height: 20px;">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.mine` not `#mine` (which is for ID.)

give `display:inline-block` for childer of `mine`

```
.mine>button,.mine>table{
display: inline-block;float:left;
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;

}

p.pos_right {
position: relative;
left: 20px;
}

img {
display: inline-block;
z-index:-1;
}

.mine>button,.mine>table{
display: inline-block;float:left;
}

refer below code snippet.
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">    
<p>Most Number of Referrals for the month of <img src="Red-Ribbon.jpg" alt="redribbon" width="200" height="200" style="vertical-align:top"> </p>
</div>

<div class = "mine" align ="center">
<button style="background-color:yellow" onclick="window.location.reload()"><b>UPDATE</b></button>
<table class = "one" style=border="1" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
<tr> 
<td style="border-style:solid none solid solid;border-color:#4B7B9F;border-width:1px;">
<input type="text" name="zoom_query" style="width:100px; border:0px solid; height:17px; padding:0px 3px; position:relative;"> 
</td>
<td style="border-style:solid;border-color:#4B7B9F;border-width:1px;"> 
<input type="submit" value="" style="border-style: none; background: url('searchbutton3.gif') no-repeat; width: 24px; height: 20px;">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of many ways to achieve this would be to put the button in its own

```
<td>
```

tag inside the row of the table. I.e.

```
<table class = "one" style=border="1" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
<tr> 
<td>
    <button style="background-color:yellow" onclick="window.location.reload()"><b>UPDATE</b></button>
</td>
...
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/orndorffgrant/189judf0/
.

The reason that there was a line break is that there is an implicit line break before and after every table.